# Is it possible to send an fb notification from external website? For example, www.xxxx.com will send a notification to a certain fb user

Tags: fbconnect

For example, www.xxxx.com will send a notification to a certain fb user.

```
 POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?
 access_token= … & 
 href= … & 
 template=@[596824621] started a game with you, play now!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that sending notifications to facebook users via external website is not possible, but sending messages with the permission of user and posting to wall will do.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Requests are only available for games on Facebook.com or iOS and Android apps. Accepting a request from a game will direct the person to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. For native mobile apps, accepting the request will direct the person to the app on their device if installed or to the appropriate location (Apple App Store or Google Play) to download the app otherwise

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: But it is noted "Requests are only available for games on Facebook.com or iOS and Android apps"

Comment: Yeah you might want to check this one too. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui